# chrome serial API JavaScript cannot access client ports issue

Tags: javascript, serial-port

Im trying to use [Chrome web Serial API](https://github.com/UnJavaScripter/web-serial-example) to communicating with serial ports in a local machine. it works fine even hosted in local IIS. But it doesn't work when run from a server. JavaScript is client side language so why this difference?  is there anyway to correct this by giving some privileges by changing below script ? or is there some more chrome experimental features to achieve this  ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Web Serial</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="serial-scale-div">
        <button class="btn" id="connect-to-serial">Connect with Serial Device</button>
  </div>

  <button id="get-serial-messages">Get serial messages</button>
  
  <div id="serial-messages-container">
    <div class="message"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    "use strict";
    class SerialScaleController {
        constructor() {
            this.encoder = new TextEncoder();
            this.decoder = new TextDecoder();
        }
        async init() {
            if ('serial' in navigator) {
                try {
                    const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
                    await port.open({ baudrate: 9600 });
                    this.reader = port.readable.getReader();
                    let signals = await port.getSignals();
                    console.log(signals);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.error('There was an error opening the serial port:', err);
                }
            }
            else {
                console.error('Web serial doesn\'t seem to be enabled in your browser. Try enabling it by visiting:');
                console.error('chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features');
                console.error('opera://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features');
                console.error('edge://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features');
            }
        }
        async read() {
            try {
                const readerData = await this.reader.read();
                console.log(readerData)
                return this.decoder.decode(readerData.value);
            }
            catch (err) {
                const errorMessage = `error reading data: ${err}`;
                console.error(errorMessage);
                return errorMessage;
            }
        }
    }

    const serialScaleController = new SerialScaleController();
    const connect = document.getElementById('connect-to-serial');
    const getSerialMessages = document.getElementById('get-serial-messages');

    connect.addEventListener('pointerdown', () => {
      serialScaleController.init();
    });

    getSerialMessages.addEventListener('pointerdown', async () => {
      getSerialMessage();
    });

    async function getSerialMessage() {
      document.querySelector("#serial-messages-container .message").innerText += await serialScaleController.read()
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```